# Strange border on chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

Strange border on chrome like the picture, when clicked anywhere it disappears

Thanks your help

[image]

CSS:

```
.ui-jqdialog .ui-jqdialog-titlebar-close:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.ui-jqdialog .ui-jqdialog-titlebar-close {
      border: none;
      background: transparent;
      opacity: 0.4;
      color: #d15b47;
      padding: 0;
      top: 50%;
      right: 8px !important;
      text-align: center;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function openView(id) {
          var url = '<s:url value="/www/calendar/ViewEvents.action?id=" />' + id                       
                    + "&fromWidget=true";
          $.get(url, function(html) {
            $('#eventContent').html(html);
            $( "#eventContent" ).removeClass('hide').dialog({
              modal: true,
              title: "<div class='widget-header widget-header-small'>
                      <h4 class='smaller'><s:text name="calendar" /></h4>                         
                      </div>",
              width: 500,
              title_html: true,
              buttons: []
            });
          });
        }
```

Comment: Could you also provide the HTML code?

Comment: that CSS wouldn't cause that - the code posted is nowhere near enough to determine where the border is coming from

Comment: Its too early to come to a conclusion without looking at the website. But, It could be because of the css outline attribute.

Comment: It without jsp code still happen there

Comment: seems like the default 'outline' for inputs on chrome. Try to set 'outline' to none

Comment: @Geert-Jan cool it fix with your answer